# A Clojure binding question

Tags: clojure

just looking to re factor some simple code

I have a function

```
(defn foo
    ([x y]
        (let [line [x y]]
            (...))
    ([x y z]
        (let [plane [x y z]]
            (...))))
```

I know I can write

```
(let [[x y :as point] [1 0]])
```

Is there a similar destructuring for functions such as `foo` where I can write 
`[x y :as line]` or `[x y z :as plane]` in the actual defn? (i.e plane would be assigned [x y z])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always build the `let`s using a macro. This would enable you to two write something like:

```
(def foo
  (build-foo-args [[x y] line]
     (...))
  (build-foo-args [[x y z] plane]
     (...)))
```

Not sure how much this syntactic sugar really buys you though... the lets are pretty clear in the first place.

On the whole, I'd probably recommend rethinking your function signature:

- If you genuinely need different behaviours for different arities then
  foo should probably be split into separate functions.
- If the behaviour is the same for different arities, then I would use
  variadic args as suggested by Dave Ray, but call the combined
  argument something neutral e.g. "normal-vector" which can refer to multiple
  dimensionalities. You may find you don't actually need x,y,z to be named at all....

Answer (score 2):

You can destructure in the arg list as well, but you'll have to use variadic args which means you can't have multiple signatures:

```
(defn foo [& [x y z :as plane]]
  (...))
```

and then call like:

```
(foo 1 2 3)
```

but like I said above, with this approach the two and three arg forms become ambiguous so you'd have to have separate named functions.

Comment: thats the problem :) I want the multiple arg forms, I guess I need to learn to write macros to implement this?